# Toggle Off/On Google Fusion Layer (Google Javascript API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to toggle off/on a county layer (var county) from a google fusion table in my google map but I have been having trouble getting the code that I am using to work.  I researched some examples on how to do this and am using one a recent code example.  Any help with identifying how to correct this is greatly appreciated.  I am attaching my full code.  Thank you.

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Web Map of WVDRS Offices</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<style type="text/css"> 
html, body, #map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
} 
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> 
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript">

function toggleLayer(this_layer){
  if(this_layer.getMap()) {
    this_layer.setMap(null)
  } else {
    this_layer.setMap(map);
  }
}

var county=null;
var state=null;

function initialize() { 
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.895308,-80.304565);  
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

 var county = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col2",
    from: "1lFbxbsOiMmrxnxhiVEf5ayUzLVGqt2HUCKOnSOSf",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 3
  }
});

var state = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col0",
    from: "18_J2uuiZRLon48Lc6bclZ0ckHanbKZB9qg319KV3",
    where: "col2 \x3d 30"
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions) ;

    county.setMap(map);
    state.setMap(map);   

lats = new Array     (38.321099,38.4579809,38.801414,38.843651,38.819064,39.28549,39.4848327,39.627854,39.018054,38.939379,40.065522,39.26451,40.401822,39.564031,37.790201,37.3602823,37.828694,38.304694,38.401603,37.847892,37.584431,39.496909,39.401623,39.3356127,37.415833,38.014136,39.070254);
longs = new Array (-81.581721,-81.931094,-81.351222,-82.138137,-81.722606,-80.270051,-80.1418304,-79.930129,-80.421569,-79.856733,-80.722743,-81.559587,-80.587742,-80.996412,-81.190381,-81.0978385,-80.420059,-80.830412,-82.492229,-81.993212,-81.38147,-77.954339,-79.015217,-78.7457004,-81.589306,-81.125976,-78.938935);
hovertitle = new Array ("Charleston WVDRS","Teays Valley WVDRS","Spencer WVDRS","Point Pleasant WVDRS","Ripley WVDRS","Clarksburg WVDRS","Fairmont WVDRS","Morgantown WVDRS","Weston WVDRS","Elkins WVDRS","Wheeling WVDRS","Parkersburg WVDRS","Weirton WVDRS","Sistersville WVDRS","Beckley WVDRS","Princeton WVDRS","Lewisburg WVDRS","Summersville WVDRS","Huntington WVDRS","Logan WVDRS","Mullens WVDRS","Martinsburg WVDRS","Keyser WVDRS","Romney WVDRS","Welch WVDRS","Oak Hill WVDRS","Moorefield WVDRS");
htmlAll = new Array ("<h5>Charleston WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Charleston.png width=200 height=150><p>4701 MacCorkle Avenue SE<br>Charleston, WV 25304<br>304-356-2371(Phone)<br>304-926-1710(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Charleston.html>Get Directions</a></p>", 
                    "<h5>Teays Valley WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150 alt=NeedPictureOfOffice><p>115 Liberty Square<br>Hurricane, WV 25526<br>304-760-7082(Phone)<br>304-759-0267(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/TeaysValley.html>Get Directions</a></p>",
                    "<h5>Spencer WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Spencer.png width=200 height=150><p>321 Market Street<br>Spencer, WV 25276<br>304-927-0954(Phone)<br>304-927-0955(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Spencer.html>Get Directions</a></p>",
                    "<h5>Point Pleasant WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/PointPleasant.png width=200 height=150><p>209 5th Street<br>Point Pleasant, WV 25550<br>304-675-0867(Phone)<br>304-675-0882(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/PointPleasant.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Ripley WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>206 Stone Drive<br>Ripley, WV 25271<br>304-373-0313(Phone)<br>304-373-0116(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Ripley.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Clarksburg WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>107 Cambridge Place<br>Bridgeport, WV 26330<br>304-842-2951(Phone)<br>304-842-4826(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Clarksburg.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Fairmont WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Fairmont.png width=200 height=150><p>Veterans Square<br>320 Adams Street, Suite 106<br>Fairmont, WV 26554<br>304-367-2714(Phone)<br>304-367-2716(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Fairmont.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Morgantown WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Morgantown.png width=200 height =150><p>1415 Earl Core Road<br>Morgantown, WV 26505<br>304-285-3155(Phone)<br>304-285-3158(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Morgantown.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Weston WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height =150><p>306 Market Place Mall<br>Weston, WV 26451<br>304-269-0547(Phone)<br>304-269-0427(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Weston.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Elkins WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height =150><p>1025 North Randolph Avenue<br>Elkins, WV 26241<br>304-637-0205(Phone)<br>304-637-0209(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Elkins.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Wheeling WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Wheeling.png width=200 height=150><p>Central Union Building<br>40 14th Street, Suite 103<br>Wheeling, WV 26003<br>304-238-1093(Phone)<br>304-238-1096(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Wheeling.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Parkersburg WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Parkersburg.png width=200 height=150><p>State Office Building<br>400 5th Street<br>Parkersburg, WV 26101<br>304-420-4580(Phone)<br>304-420-4583(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Parkersburg.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Weirton WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Weirton.png width=200 height=150><p>100 Municipal Plaza, Suite 200<br>Weirton, WV 26062<br>304-723-5311(Phone)<br>304-723-5318(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Weirton.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Sistersville WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>714 Wells Street<br>Sistersville, WV 26175<br>304-652-2354(Phone)<br>304-652-2359(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Sistersville.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Beckley WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>800 New River Town Center<br>Beckley, WV 25801<br>304-256-6900(Phone)<br>304-256-6903(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Beckley.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Princeton WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>195 Davis Street<br>Princeton, WV 24739<br>304-425-1256(Phone)<br>304-487-2631(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Princeton.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Lewisburg WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Lewisburg.png width=200 height=150><p>777 North Jefferson Street, Suite 105<br>Lewisburg, WV 24901<br>304-647-7515(Phone)<br>304-647-7518(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Lewisburg.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Summersville WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>830 Northside Drive, Suite 113<br>Summersville, WV 26651<br>304-872-0813(Phone)<br>304-872-0518(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Summersville.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Huntington WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Huntington.png width=200 height=150><p>2699 Park Avenue, Suite 200<br>Huntington, WV 25704<br>304-528-5585(Phone)<br>304-528-5591(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Huntington.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Logan WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>130 Stratton Street<br>Logan, WV 25601<br>304-792-7060(Phone)<br>304-792-7062(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Logan.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Mullens WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>316 Howard Avenue<br>Mullens,WV 25882<br>304-294-5653(Phone)<br>304-294-5655(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Mullens.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Martinsburg WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>489 Mid Atlantic Parkway, Suite 2<br>Martinsburg, WV 25404<br>304-267-0005(Phone)<br>304-267-0007(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Martinsburg.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Keyser WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>67 North Tornado Way<br>Keyser, WV 26726<br>304-788-2313(Phone)<br>304-788-6389(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Keyser.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Romney WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Romney.png width=200 height=150><p>24948 Northwestern Pike<br>Romney, WV 26757<br>304-822-3957<br>304-822-7417</p><p><a href=directions/Romney.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Welch WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>110 Park Avenue<br>Welch, WV 24801<br>304-436-3175(Phone)<br>304-436-3176(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Welch.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Oak Hill WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>549 Mall Road<br>Oak Hill, WV 25901<br>304-465-3025(Phone)<br>304-465-3069(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/OakHill.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Moorefield WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150 alt=NeedPictureOfOffice><p>151 Robert C. Byrd<br>Industrial Park Road, Suite 3<br>Moorefield, WV 26836<br>304-538-2701(Phone)<br>304-538-2718(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Moorefield.html>Get Directions</a>");



markers = new Array ();
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i],longs[i]);

var contentString = htmlAll[i];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
html: htmlAll[i],
    title: hovertitle[i]
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
infowindow.setContent(this.html);
infowindow.open(map,this);

});
}}

</script> 
</head> 
<body onLoad="initialize()">
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_county" checked onchange="toggleLayer(county)"/> 
  <label> Turn off Counties </label>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div> 
<div style="text-align: center;"><div style="position:relative; top:0; margin-right:auto;margin-    left:auto; z-index:99999"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error with your code: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getMap' of null`

To be used in an HTML click event listener those objects need to be in the global scope (at least that is simplest, it can be made to work with the google.maps.event.addDomListener also).

You already have this:

```
var county=null;
var state=null;
```

You need to add this:

```
var map=null;
```

And remove the `var` keyword from the beginning of the definition of those objects inside the initialize function (that makes new versions local to the initialize function).

Working code snippet:

```js
function toggleLayer(this_layer){
  if(this_layer.getMap()) {
    this_layer.setMap(null)
  } else {
    this_layer.setMap(map);
  }
}

var county=null;
var state=null;
var map=null;

function initialize() { 
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.895308,-80.304565);  
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}

 county = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col2",
    from: "1lFbxbsOiMmrxnxhiVEf5ayUzLVGqt2HUCKOnSOSf",
    where: ""
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 3
  }
});

state = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
  map: map,
  heatmap: { enabled: false },
  query: {
    select: "col0",
    from: "18_J2uuiZRLon48Lc6bclZ0ckHanbKZB9qg319KV3",
    where: "col2 \x3d 30"
  },
  options: {
    styleId: 2,
    templateId: 2
  }
});

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions) ;

    county.setMap(map);
    state.setMap(map);   

lats = new Array     (38.321099,38.4579809,38.801414,38.843651,38.819064,39.28549,39.4848327,39.627854,39.018054,38.939379,40.065522,39.26451,40.401822,39.564031,37.790201,37.3602823,37.828694,38.304694,38.401603,37.847892,37.584431,39.496909,39.401623,39.3356127,37.415833,38.014136,39.070254);
longs = new Array (-81.581721,-81.931094,-81.351222,-82.138137,-81.722606,-80.270051,-80.1418304,-79.930129,-80.421569,-79.856733,-80.722743,-81.559587,-80.587742,-80.996412,-81.190381,-81.0978385,-80.420059,-80.830412,-82.492229,-81.993212,-81.38147,-77.954339,-79.015217,-78.7457004,-81.589306,-81.125976,-78.938935);
hovertitle = new Array ("Charleston WVDRS","Teays Valley WVDRS","Spencer WVDRS","Point Pleasant WVDRS","Ripley WVDRS","Clarksburg WVDRS","Fairmont WVDRS","Morgantown WVDRS","Weston WVDRS","Elkins WVDRS","Wheeling WVDRS","Parkersburg WVDRS","Weirton WVDRS","Sistersville WVDRS","Beckley WVDRS","Princeton WVDRS","Lewisburg WVDRS","Summersville WVDRS","Huntington WVDRS","Logan WVDRS","Mullens WVDRS","Martinsburg WVDRS","Keyser WVDRS","Romney WVDRS","Welch WVDRS","Oak Hill WVDRS","Moorefield WVDRS");
htmlAll = new Array ("<h5>Charleston WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Charleston.png width=200 height=150><p>4701 MacCorkle Avenue SE<br>Charleston, WV 25304<br>304-356-2371(Phone)<br>304-926-1710(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Charleston.html>Get Directions</a></p>", 
                    "<h5>Teays Valley WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150 alt=NeedPictureOfOffice><p>115 Liberty Square<br>Hurricane, WV 25526<br>304-760-7082(Phone)<br>304-759-0267(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/TeaysValley.html>Get Directions</a></p>",
                    "<h5>Spencer WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Spencer.png width=200 height=150><p>321 Market Street<br>Spencer, WV 25276<br>304-927-0954(Phone)<br>304-927-0955(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Spencer.html>Get Directions</a></p>",
                    "<h5>Point Pleasant WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/PointPleasant.png width=200 height=150><p>209 5th Street<br>Point Pleasant, WV 25550<br>304-675-0867(Phone)<br>304-675-0882(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/PointPleasant.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Ripley WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>206 Stone Drive<br>Ripley, WV 25271<br>304-373-0313(Phone)<br>304-373-0116(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Ripley.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Clarksburg WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>107 Cambridge Place<br>Bridgeport, WV 26330<br>304-842-2951(Phone)<br>304-842-4826(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Clarksburg.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Fairmont WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Fairmont.png width=200 height=150><p>Veterans Square<br>320 Adams Street, Suite 106<br>Fairmont, WV 26554<br>304-367-2714(Phone)<br>304-367-2716(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Fairmont.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Morgantown WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Morgantown.png width=200 height =150><p>1415 Earl Core Road<br>Morgantown, WV 26505<br>304-285-3155(Phone)<br>304-285-3158(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Morgantown.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Weston WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height =150><p>306 Market Place Mall<br>Weston, WV 26451<br>304-269-0547(Phone)<br>304-269-0427(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Weston.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Elkins WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height =150><p>1025 North Randolph Avenue<br>Elkins, WV 26241<br>304-637-0205(Phone)<br>304-637-0209(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Elkins.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Wheeling WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Wheeling.png width=200 height=150><p>Central Union Building<br>40 14th Street, Suite 103<br>Wheeling, WV 26003<br>304-238-1093(Phone)<br>304-238-1096(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Wheeling.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Parkersburg WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Parkersburg.png width=200 height=150><p>State Office Building<br>400 5th Street<br>Parkersburg, WV 26101<br>304-420-4580(Phone)<br>304-420-4583(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Parkersburg.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Weirton WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Weirton.png width=200 height=150><p>100 Municipal Plaza, Suite 200<br>Weirton, WV 26062<br>304-723-5311(Phone)<br>304-723-5318(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Weirton.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Sistersville WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>714 Wells Street<br>Sistersville, WV 26175<br>304-652-2354(Phone)<br>304-652-2359(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Sistersville.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Beckley WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>800 New River Town Center<br>Beckley, WV 25801<br>304-256-6900(Phone)<br>304-256-6903(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Beckley.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Princeton WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>195 Davis Street<br>Princeton, WV 24739<br>304-425-1256(Phone)<br>304-487-2631(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Princeton.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Lewisburg WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Lewisburg.png width=200 height=150><p>777 North Jefferson Street, Suite 105<br>Lewisburg, WV 24901<br>304-647-7515(Phone)<br>304-647-7518(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Lewisburg.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Summersville WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>830 Northside Drive, Suite 113<br>Summersville, WV 26651<br>304-872-0813(Phone)<br>304-872-0518(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Summersville.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Huntington WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Huntington.png width=200 height=150><p>2699 Park Avenue, Suite 200<br>Huntington, WV 25704<br>304-528-5585(Phone)<br>304-528-5591(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Huntington.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Logan WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>130 Stratton Street<br>Logan, WV 25601<br>304-792-7060(Phone)<br>304-792-7062(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Logan.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Mullens WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>316 Howard Avenue<br>Mullens,WV 25882<br>304-294-5653(Phone)<br>304-294-5655(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Mullens.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Martinsburg WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>489 Mid Atlantic Parkway, Suite 2<br>Martinsburg, WV 25404<br>304-267-0005(Phone)<br>304-267-0007(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Martinsburg.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Keyser WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>67 North Tornado Way<br>Keyser, WV 26726<br>304-788-2313(Phone)<br>304-788-6389(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Keyser.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Romney WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/Romney.png width=200 height=150><p>24948 Northwestern Pike<br>Romney, WV 26757<br>304-822-3957<br>304-822-7417</p><p><a href=directions/Romney.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Welch WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>110 Park Avenue<br>Welch, WV 24801<br>304-436-3175(Phone)<br>304-436-3176(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Welch.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Oak Hill WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150><p>549 Mall Road<br>Oak Hill, WV 25901<br>304-465-3025(Phone)<br>304-465-3069(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/OakHill.html>Get Directions</a>",
                    "<h5>Moorefield WVDRS</h5><img src=offices/webmapDefault.png width=200 height=150 alt=NeedPictureOfOffice><p>151 Robert C. Byrd<br>Industrial Park Road, Suite 3<br>Moorefield, WV 26836<br>304-538-2701(Phone)<br>304-538-2718(Fax)</p><p><a href=directions/Moorefield.html>Get Directions</a>");



markers = new Array ();
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lats[i],longs[i]);

var contentString = htmlAll[i];
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: contentString
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
html: htmlAll[i],
    title: hovertitle[i]
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { 
infowindow.setContent(this.html);
infowindow.open(map,this);

});
}}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"> </script> 
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="show_hide_county" checked onchange="toggleLayer(county)"/> 
  <label> Turn off Counties </label>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div> 
<div style="text-align: center;"><div style="position:relative; top:0; margin-right:auto;margin-    left:auto; z-index:99999"></div>
```